# norm of difference of similar matrice

Tags: normed-spaces, estimation

Let $a,b \in C^n$; $A, B\in C^{n\times n}$.
If $A$ and $B$ are similar matrices, i.e. there exists nonsingular $S\in C^{n\times n}$ such that $B=S^{-1}AS$, is it possible to proof an inequality in the following form
$$
\|B.a-A.b\| \leq Q.\|a-b\|
$$
where $Q$ is some expression and the norm is any vector norm?

Comment: Do you want $Q$ to be independent of $a$ and $b$?

Comment: No. $Q$ may be any expression.

Answer (score 1):

Take $a = b$. If $Q$ were to exist, we should have that $\|Ba - Aa\| = 0$. Hence,

$$
0 = Ba-Aa = (B-A)a.
$$

Note that this is absurd when $a \not \in \ker (B-A)$. For example, take $a = e_1$, $B = 2I_n, A = I_n$.

Comment: The vectors $a\not= b$.